# Have usage in the example

Tags: word-usage

I was reading BBClearning app, in that a quiz conversation given at the end of the page as follows,

Finn : And number3. Daughters-in-law. With hyphens.

Alice : True!

Finn : That's right, it has hyphens. **Well done if you got those right.**

I have a doubt with the sentence that it should have "have" in it as **"Well done  if you have got those right"**

Why the sentence has no *have* in it? The answer by the person Alice was not entirely happened in the past. It was just happened when he asked the question. Can someone explain why there is no "have" in the sentence?

May be my knowledge of using "have" could be wrong. So help me.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present perfect ("have got") is possible, but in this context the simple past ("got") is more idiomatic. I think it's because the quiz (or, at least, that question) is complete.

As often in tenses in English, more than one choice is possible for the same circumstances, and gives a very slightly different flavour to what is being said. "Have got" would be regarding the experience of the question as continuing to now - perhaps emphasising that the person has their answer still in front of them. "Got", as I say, treats it as complete.